# OData V4 System.DateTime breaking change

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2

I am attempting to convert V3 to V4. However, the conversion revealed the removal of support for System.DateTime as found in http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1753. I cannot change the model to use offset. There are other questions about this, but there is no work around provided.

I attemtped to do something like this:

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
var config = builder.EntitySet<DepartmentListItem>("DepartmentList");
config.EntityType.Ignore(x => x.StartDate);
var ops = new ODataQueryOptions<DepartmentListItem>(new ODataQueryContext(builder.GetEdmModel(), typeof(DepartmentListItem), null), queryOptions.Request);
var query = ops.ApplyTo(_uow.Set<DepartmentListItem>()).Cast<DepartmentListItem>();
```

just to get it to work but to no avail. Is there anyway to handle this conversion manually.

Thanks.

Comment: Vote for https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/2072 and http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/147201-asp-net-web-api/suggestions/6242255-odata-v4-service-should-support-datetime

Answer (score 6):

(SO tells me I'm too green to post a comment so posting a reply instead)

I emphatically agree with Gareth. We have a very well established EDMX-based EF environment used by a number of apps (WPF, MVC). Its not possible, verging on ridiculous, to consider modifying such just to get around V4 team's lack of appreciation that EF exists to support databases and not repository-less conceptual data models. Going back to V3 until a reality check sorts this out (maybe V4.1?).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what kind of questions you have. My project is using EntityFrameworkModel with webAPI. When i tried to migrate from V3 to V4. I got the same issue. My Solution is like following:

1.Change the CLRObject in your model

```
//Represent the data in DB
private Nullable<DateTime> OrderDateOnInternal { get; set; }

//Data exposed by Service
public Nullable<DateTimeOffset> OrderDate                                  
{ 
    get { return new DateTimeOffset(OrderDateOnInternal.Value);}
    set { OrderDateOnInternal = value.Value.DateTime; }
}
```

2. change the model defination in conceptualModels in ***Model.edmx which is generated from my DataBase.

The original generated CSDL Content for OrderDate is like

```
<Property Name="OrderDate" Type="DateTime" Precision="3" />
```

Then i changed it to

```
<Property Name="OrderDateOnInternal" Type="DateTime" Precision="3" />
```

3. Change the mapping in c-s mapping content

The original generated mapping content is like

```
<ScalarProperty Name="OrderDate" ColumnName="OrderDate" />
```

Then i changed it to

```
<ScalarProperty Name="OrderDateOnInternal" ColumnName="OrderDate" />
```

This works for me.

Comment: The problem with this is that you are customizing your Entity Framework model to your OData.  If you have your model in a separate library and plan on using it for both OData and other projects (backend services and console apps, for instance), then those other processes now have to work with DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime as well.  Ideally, you could convert the values in the OdataConventionModelBuilder, so the regular model is left intact.

Comment: I agree with Gareth. This is a nonstarter for existing EF models already in use.

Comment: This is also a poor solution when you have around 300 properties that will need to be modified to work with OData V4.  NOTE: I am not saying there is a better way, but rather it was extremely short sighted of Microsoft to not support both DateTime and DateTimeOffset.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in control of the client, I recently discovered you can resolve the problem by casting to Edm.DateTimeOffset.  Here's an example of what helped me get over this hurdle:

Request Prior to OData v4: `/odata/item?$filter=someDate+gt+datetime'2016-06-16'`

OData v4 Request: `/odata/item?$filter=someDate+gt+cast(2016-06-16, Edm.DateTimeOffset)`

Hope that helps.